# Menu to not refresh

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, refresh

I don't know if this is possible or not, but on my website menu I have a chat box which you can toggle.  Whenever you click on another link, the chat box hides itself which I don't want.
Is there a way that if someone clicks on another page, it avoids the menu being refreshed with the rest of the website, so that it will remember the toggle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use cookie for storing its current state, default will be hidden say 0. So, if a user clicks on it it will get opened and cookie will have open (1) value. And on page refresh it will first look for cookies value, if that is present it will work accordingly.